# What "restart" shows in PM2 list command

Tags: pm2

when I execute command pm2 list it shows following output will columns :

```
App name    id  mode  pid     status   restart  uptime  memory  watching
```

what is significance of **restart** column here ?

Answer (score 1):

`restart` column in PM2 shows how many times that particular script was restarted.

So if you initially start a script it will be `0` as in the below output.

```
┌──────────┬────┬──────┬───────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ App name │ id │ mode │ pid   │ status │ restart │ uptime │ cpu │ mem      │ watching │
├──────────┼────┼──────┼───────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼─────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ server   │ 0  │ fork │ 10505 │ online │ 0       │ 0s     │ 0%  │ 14.0 MB  │ disabled │
└──────────┴────┴──────┴───────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

When you run the command `pm2 restart script.js` the output will be as below.

```
┌──────────┬────┬──────┬───────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ App name │ id │ mode │ pid   │ status │ restart │ uptime │ cpu │ mem      │ watching │
├──────────┼────┼──────┼───────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼─────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ server   │ 0  │ fork │ 10525 │ online │ 1       │ 0s     │ 0%  │ 11.5 MB  │ disabled │
└──────────┴────┴──────┴───────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

The value of restart is `1`, and it will be incremented every time you restart the script.

Comment: restarted by pm2. when restarting manually pm2 wont be able to track that. so `restart` is actually a count which tells that how many times it has been restart using `pm2`.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the restart column lists all restarts.

When you use 'pm2 restart process.js' or 'pm2 restart process_name', that adds to the restart count.

When pm2 restarts the process automatically if it crashes, that adds to the restart count as well.

It's rather simple to try out, make a simple node file, run it, restart it, make an error in the code, run it again to see the automatic restarts increasing the count.